# Show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{x\in X} a_n(x) = \sum_{x\in X}\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis

> Let $X$ be a finite set, let $m$ be an integer, and for each $x \in X$ let
>   $(a_n(x))_{n=m}^{\infty}$ be a convergent sequence of real numbers. Show that the sequence $(\sum_{x\in X} a_n(x))_{n=m}^{\infty}$ is convergent, and
>
> $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{x\in X} a_n(x) = \sum_{x\in X}\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n(x)$$
>   (Hint: induct on the cardinality of $X$)

Let's denote the cardinality of $X$ by $k = |X|$.

Base case: $k = 0$.
 Hence, $X$ is an empty set. However, since $X$ is empty then there is no $a_n(x)$ for any $x \in X$, which means that this sequence is empty too. The sum over the empty sequence is equal to $0$ by definition. Therefore, $(\sum_{x\in X} a_n(x))_{n=m}^{\infty}$ converges to $0$. Also for the same reason $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{x\in X} a_n(x) = 0$. However, **I have a problem** with $\sum_{x\in X}\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n(x)$, because it was never definied (at least I didn't find it) in my book (Terence Tao-Analysis 1) the limit of the empty sequence.

Inductive step: Assume the statement holds for $k$, show for $k+1$.
Can be helpful:

Let $f:X \to R$, such that $f(x) = a_n(x)$, and since $X$ is finite then there exists a bijection $g:$ {$1,2,...,k$} $\to X$. Then by definition of the finite sum $\sum_{x\in X} a_n(x) = \sum_{x\in X} f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{k} f(g(i))$.

If $(a_n(x))_{n=m}^{\infty}$ is convergent then for any positive real $\epsilon > 0$, there exist $N > m$ such that $|a_n - L| < \epsilon$ for all $n > N$.
By the inductive hypothesis, we know that $\sum_{i=1}^{k} f(g(i))$ is also convergent i.e. $|\sum_{i=1}^{k} f(g(i)) - L'|< \epsilon$. We should show that $|\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} f(g(i)) - L'| = |\sum_{i=1}^{k} f(g(i)) + f(g(k+1)) - L'|< \epsilon$. If it is convergent than using the sum of the limits law we would get that 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{x\in X} a_n(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{k+1} f(g(i)) = \lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^{k} f(g(i)) + f(g(k+1)) = \sum_{x\in X}\lim_{n \to \infty} f(g(i)) + \lim_{n \to \infty} f(g(k+1))$$

How to finish the base case and how to show the convergence of the sum of the sequence in the inductive step?

Answer (score 0):

*Hint*

One can prove that if $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ converges to $x$ and $y$ respectively, then $(x_n+y_n)$ converges to $x+y$. The claim follow by induction.

Comment: Yes I know that but struggle to see how it can be helpful to show the convergence of the sum of the sequence. Though, I used it here (assuming that the sum of the sequence is convergent) $\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^{k} f(g(i)) + f(g(k+1)) = \sum_{x\in X}\lim_{n \to \infty} f(g(i)) + \lim_{n \to \infty} f(g(k+1))$